# Django: Queryset que devuelva el objeto padre junto con sus hijos que cumplan una condición

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy construyendo una *API* con *Django Rest Framework* y en uno de mis *endpoints*, necesito devolver un `array` de objetos, padres e hijos, que cumplan la condición `active = true`

Estos son mis modelos

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Y este mi `query set`

```
queryset = Category.objects.filter(products__active=True)
```

Tengo mi `serializer` configurado para que devuelva tanto las categorías como sus productos.

Me gustaría que la respuesta fuese todas las categorías con sus productos activos pero devuelve tanto los productos activos como los inactivos.

Imagino que será una tontería pero no tengo mucha experiencia en *Django*

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: [esto es lo que quieres hacer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354281/5695795)

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te sugiero realizar algo como esto:

```
Product.objects.select_related('category').filter(active=True)
```

Lo que hara esto es seleccionar todo lo relacionado a **category** o tu foreingKey.

Para mayor referencia te sugiero revisar: [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego por tu respuesta. Así me funciona pero no es exactamente lo que buscaba porque efectivamente me devuelve solo los productos activos de todas las categorías, pero yo necesito que me devuelva un array de Categorías junto con sus productos activos.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que necesitarás que tanto categoría como producto estén activos.La query para obtener lo que comentas sería:

```
queryset = Category.objects.select_related('products').filter(active=True, products__active=True)
```

Esta query por definición te devuelve las categorías activas con sus productos activos. Dado que necesitas también los productos se usa `select_related` para que te lo traiga todo en una única query, incluyendo la relación, en este caso productos, de lo contrario, lanzaría dos queries una para categorías y otra para productos bajo demanda cuando quieras acceder a ellos.